# flutter firebase phone authentication not working when the app is installed from play store

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am aware that there are "duplicates" of this but all of them say the same thing that I have tried. 
I have added the SHA1 and SHA256 key to the firebase project.

The OTP verification works well in the debug mode or when I manually install the release apk. But it doesn't when the app is downloaded from play store, the OTP is not sent at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 set of keys in google play console. One is upload key and another one is app sign in key. You should add the keys from app sign in key section in firebase to get this working.
After adding these keys you have to download json from firebase and add it to the project too

Comment: yes, I found that out and fixed it, so much for non-tech project managers. Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Update SHA-1 Key in Firebase project setting

[image]

Also check your google cloud project api key setting and also add SHA-1 Key credentials if you have Key restrictions.

[image]